# Could not find method ksp() for arguments

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-symbol-processing

I just started learning about Android in Kotlin and I was creating a note application just for learning purposes. I wanted to use Room to store saved notes in my database, so i was checking out the developer.android tutorials and We have some  necessary dependencies which we have to add in our build.gradle(Module) as mentioned on developer.android.com https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#kts
but when i add these dependencies i am having an error which i'm not able to figure out

> Could not find method ksp() for arguments [androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

I was having the similar error with kapt, but i solved it by adding the necessary plugin in my build.gradle(Module).For now i am removing this implementation from my build.gradle and moving ahead with the test project, but any help would be appreciated, thankyou.

**dependencies mentioned in the developer.android.com**

```
dependencies {
    val room_version = "2.4.3"

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    // To use Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP)
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")

    // optional - RxJava2 support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version")

    // optional - RxJava3 support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room_version")

    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation("androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version")

    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version")

    // optional - Paging 3 Integration
    implementation("androidx.room:room-paging:$room_version")
}
```

**my build.gradle(Module)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'

}
android {
    namespace 'android.example.mynotes'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.example.mynotes"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    def room_version = "2.4.3"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

    implementation("com.google.devtools.ksp:symbol-processing-api:1.8.0-1.0.8")

    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

}
```

**my build.gradle(Project)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the project **gradle.build** file upgrade the kotlin gradle plugin to 1.8.0 in the `plugins{ ... }` block.

```
// Project level build file

plugins {
    ...
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

On the App(mudule) **gradle.build** file you don't need to set *kapt()*, just add `ksp()` in the `dependencies{ ... }` block and also set the KSP plugin

```
// App module build file

plugins{
    ...
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.8.0-1.0.8'
}

dependencies {
   
    ...
    // You don't need this
    // kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    ...

}
```

Comment: Can someone please explain where in the project's gradle.build file the plugin section should go? No matter where I put it, it reports errors that plugins is unknown

Comment: I am getting an error: rror resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.8.0', apply: false]
> The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with an unknown version, so compatibility cannot be checked.

Comment: @Rafael I think you should update/upgrade all dependencies on your project to their latest versions

Comment: What does "apply false" do here? Also, when I removed kapt in the past it threw an error.

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you're kotlin gradle plugin version is 1.8.0: or higher

`classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0'`

In the app level gradle file add dependency

`id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.8.0-1.0.8'`

Finally, build your project.

Comment: Where should we add the classpath parth?

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi You should add it to your projects grade.build file, not to module level gradle.build.

Comment: id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.8.0-1.0.8'  should be added to plugins block in module level build.gradle file

Answer (score 8):

according to this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp)

First, declare the KSP plugin in your top level build.gradle.kts file. Make sure that you choose a KSP version aligned with your project's Kotlin version

```
plugins {
   id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.10-1.0.9" apply false
}
```

Then, enable KSP in your module-level build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins {
   id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}
```

Comment: Worked for me when I set ksp plugin version '1.9.0-1.0.13' for project using Kotlin version '1.9.0'.

Comment: You just saved my sanity @ElectroBuddha, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to declare the KSP plugin in your top-level build(Project). gradle.kt file. Make sure that you choose a KSP version aligned with your project's Kotlin version.

**If you are using Kotlin - build.gradle.kts**(Project level)

```
plugins {
     id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.10-1.0.9" apply false
}
```

**If you are using Groovy- build.gradle**(Project level)

```
plugins {
     id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.8.10-1.0.9' apply false
}
```

Then, enable **KSP** in your module-level or app-level build.gradle.kts file:

**Kotlin - build.gradle.kts**(module-level or app-level)

```
plugins {
     id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}
```

**Groovy - build.gradle**(module-level or app-level)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp'
}
```

Replace annotation processors with **KSP**

```
   //For .kts
dependencies {
    //When you have no dependencies included with kapt in your module anymore, remove the kapt plugin.
    //kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0")
}
//For Groovy
dependencies {
    //When you have no dependencies included with kapt in your module anymore, remove the kapt plugin.
    //kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0'
    ksp 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0'
}
```

You should also remove any leftover configuration related to kapt.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the answer from [Google codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-persisting-data-room)

1- add plugin in app/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    ...
    // ksp for room
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version "1.8.21-1.0.11"
}
```

2- add dependencies in app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    def room_version = "2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
}
```