# Android Kotlin KSP plugin with Gradle Catalogs

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to use [Room](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room) on my Android project that I'm using with the [Gradle Version Catalogs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html) feature.
Room is [officialy suported since version 2.3.0-beta02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room?hl=pt-br#2.3.0-beta02), but I'm having a problem to make them work together.

What I have now configured is something like this:

`libs.versions.toml`

```ini
[versions]
agp = "8.1.2"
// ...
androidx-room = "2.3.0-beta02"
com-google-devtools-ksp = "1.8.10-1.0.9"



[libraries]

# Implementations
core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "core-ktx" }
// ...
androidx-room-ktx = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-ktx", version.ref = "androidx.room" }
androidx-room-runtime = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-runtime", version.ref = "androidx.room" }
androidx-room-compiler = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-compiler", version.ref = "androidx.room" }


[plugins]
com-android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
// ...
com-google-devtools-ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "com-google-devtools-ksp" }


[bundles]
```

`build.gradle.kts (:app)`

```kotlin
@Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION") // TODO: Remove once KTIJ-19369 is fixed
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.com.android.application)
    // ..
    alias(libs.plugins.com.google.devtools.ksp)
}

android {
    // ...
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        minSdk = 24
        // noinspection EditedTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.core.ktx)
    // ...
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.runtime)
    ksp(libs.androidx.room.compiler)


    //    Test
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)


    //    Test Android

    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    testImplementation(libs.io.insert.koin.test)
}
```

`build.gradle.kts (Top-level build file)`

```kotlin
@Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION")
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.com.android.application) apply false
    /// ...
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize) apply false
}
true // Needed to make the Suppress annotation work for the plugins block
```

The error I'm getting is this one:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation_Decorated cannot be cast to class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.pm20.KotlinCompilationData (org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation_Decorated is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @6404c62a; org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.pm20.KotlinCompilationData is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @3df7681e)

(...)

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

(...)

org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation_Decorated cannot be cast to class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.pm20.KotlinCompilationData (org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation_Decorated is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @6404c62a; org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.pm20.KotlinCompilationData is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @3df7681e)

(...)
```

And this one:

```
class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation_Decorated cannot be cast to class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.pm20.KotlinCompilationData (org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation_Decorated is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @6404c62a; org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.pm20.KotlinCompilationData is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @3df7681e)
class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation_Decorated cannot be cast to class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.pm20.KotlinCompilationData (org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation_Decorated is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @6404c62a; org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.pm20.KotlinCompilationData is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @3df7681e)

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Answer (score 0):

`KSP` support came to Room with `2.6.0` version.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room?hl=tr#version_26_2)

You are using `2.3.0-beta02`

For correct [installation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room?hl=en#declaring_dependencies).

Comment: I changed to this `androidx-room = "2.6.0"`  but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure you installed ksp correctly?

Comment: Apart from what I showed in my snipets, what could not be correct in my project regarding the ksp installaton?

Comment: can you share on github

Comment: Not the whole project. I guess it was you I was helping with the Multi Module discussion. If you say you have some time today and that's a good idea, we can talk about our problems over discord, meet, teams...

Comment: I'm busy. I hope the community here gives the correct answer.dude

Comment: That's ok man. But what other thing you will need to see apart from what I mentioned? I could post it here and could be helpfull for other people trying to answer my question.

Comment: Also, if you can help me here, we could [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255770/discussion-between-leonardo-sibela-and-d).

Comment: Can you try agp 8.1.0?

Comment: It still didn't work and it outputs the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else face this issue try to check your kotlin version, if you have 1.9, set ksp = "1.9.0-1.0.13"

It doesn't seem to have anything to do with version catalog, as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75071164/15479315